# Calling an awk script defined in a powershell variable

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, awk

I am using awk in Powershell , so I want to get the same result of what I get from a bash script.
This awk Script is multiline, so I could do a separate file for the script such as `firstScript.awk` , but ultimately I want the Powershell Script to be able to contain that awk script (so not to clutter this with separate files)

I have succesfully done it with bash such as

```
firstScript='
$1 == "Default" && $2 == "Gateway" && $13 {
    for (i = 6; i > 1; i--) {
        if ( match(prev[i], /IPv4/) ) {
            print prev[i]
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i = 6; i > 1; i--) {
        prev[i] = prev[i - 1]
    }
    prev[1] = $0
}
'

awk "$firstScript" ./input.txt
```

This syntax does work for bash ( `awk '$firstScript' ./input.txt` would not work)

So I go now to **Powershell** and try to do the same, with the Powershell Escaping Characters considerations and other Syntax Considerations

```
$firstScript = @"
`$1 == "Default" && `$2 == "Gateway" && `$13 {
    for (i = 6; i > 1; i--) {
        if ( match(prev[i], /IPv4/) ) {
            print prev[i]
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i = 6; i > 1; i--) {
        prev[i] = prev[i - 1]
    }
    prev[1] = `$0
}
"@
ipconfig.exe | awk "$firstScript"
```

This wont work , wont show anything.

Whereas if I write a file such as
`firstScript.awk`

```
$1 == "Default" && $2 == "Gateway" && $13 {
    for (i = 6; i > 1; i--) {
        if ( match(prev[i], /IPv4/) ) {
            print prev[i]
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i = 6; i > 1; i--) {
        prev[i] = prev[i - 1]
    }
    prev[1] = $0
}
```

Then call it from other file or directly in the prompt

```
PS > ipconfig.exe | awk -f firstScript.awk
```

It works

How could I correct the above Powershell script to parse the variable properly as an outter file awk script?

Comment: The sad reality in Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell (Core) _up to v7.2.x_ is that an _extra, manual_ layer of ``\``-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to _external programs_. This is fixed in PowerShell _v7.3+_, with selective exceptions on Windows.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Aside from that you can use a _single_-quoted [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to avoid the need to escape `$` characters as `\`$`